# PHP PDO Hide Error message when failed connecting to MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to know how to hide error message when failed connecting to MySQL

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. In D:\xampp\htdocs\dhx-base-tab\data\xconn.php:13 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\dhx-base-tab\data\xconn.php(13): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127....', 'root', 'mypass') #1 {main} thrown in.
```

Especially this line when MySQL server down

`PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127....', 'root', 'mypass')`

My code:

```
$dbtype = "mysql";                              
$dbhost = "127.0.0.1";                          
$dbname = "mydb";                           
$dbuser = "root";                           
$dbpassword = "mypass";                 
$dbcharset = "utf8";        
$dsn = "mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=$dbcharset";      

try {
    $dbconn = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpassword);      
} catch (PDO $e) {
    //?????
}
```

Comment: Your `catch()` didn't look for `PDOException` however. That's why it was uncaught.

Comment: Owwh...Thank you mario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> } catch (**PDO** $e) {

PDO is not even exception.

You should use:

> } catch (**PDOException** $e) {

See [connection example with error handling](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)

Comment: Thanks for this solution po_taka

Answer (score 2):

You should set **proper PHP error reporting** for this.

PDO is doing everything all right. But what you are **really looking for** is the way to hide ALL error messages, not only PDO's. Don't your other code produce errors and throw exceptions? It does. So, why be concerned only for PDO? You have to hide them all.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

*is* the magic code you really want.

It will hide every single error from displaying to everyone. Mission accomplished.

Note that as a bonus, you don't need to use try-catch at all. Even without it, an error message wouldn't be shown at all. It will save you A LOT of useless try-catch code.

Yet, to be notified of these errors, you have to log them. To do so, anothr command have to be used.

```
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
```

You should handle ALL errors, not only the error you're aware of.

But in seems mission impossible to explain to PHP users that they should handle every error, not the only one single alone error they're aware of.

Comment: I think my mistake with PDOException..Thanks anyway